# Creating an object for one time use

Tags: ballerina

When passing an object to a function in Ballerina should we always create a variable then new it and pass it. Can't we create the object for one time use?

For example I can call the HTTP respond function as follows:

```
http:Response res;
_ = caller->respond(res);
```

But I cannot call it like this:

```
_ = caller->respond(new);
```

Is it mandatory in Ballerina to always define a variable before passing it to a function or is there a simpler workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example works. Did you come across any issues?

```
import ballerina/http;

service<http:Service> hello bind {port:9090} {
   hi (endpoint caller, http:Request request) {
      _ = caller->respond(new);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is no longer working in Ballerina 0.980 because now the respond method takes a union type and cannot infer the type of the object from new